# Performance : Load Testing in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, performance

How to perform load testing on sharepoint 2010 site without external tools ? Does developer dashboard provide load options ? I am aware of load runner and other tools .

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any tools built-in for making artificial loads on the SharePoint servers.  You would need to use or create a tool for making requests against SharePoint.

You can, however, use Performance Monitor in Windows to monitor specific performance metrics from SharePoint.  Start with [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758658(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758658%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for more information on monitoring SharePoint performance with Performance Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create something yourself, using Visual Studio.

There are numerous resources online. Take a look at [Web performance and load testing SharePoint 2010 and 2013 applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj710162.aspx), as well as [SharePoint Performance Tests](http://spperformancetest.codeplex.com/) and [MOSS Load Test](http://mossloadtest.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) (Codeplex projects) for inspiration.